# How to make a PHP file parse some data without the need for a user to stay on a page

Tags: php

I'm making a website on which administrators can upload some PDF files. I have some code that converts the uploaded PDF file (given as parameter) to plain text and, with that plain text, I can make some inserts in a database that is used to generate other pages on the website.

I could redirect the administrator that uploaded a file to another page, and on that page I could put the code to parse the file and create the database entries, but that is a slow operation and the administrator would have to stay on that page until the action completes.

Maybe I don't have the best solution, but here's how I thought it should be done: in the upload page, after a file is uploaded, the server should run a file (ex.: parsePDFFile.php) that would take care of parsing the PDF file and updating the database. That way, the administrator could keep browsing the site without being aware that there's some file processing behind the scenes.

The problem is I have no idea where to start or what to search for on Google, so I don't know if doing something like this is even possible or a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When  you upload  file. that time also enter pdf  file name  in database and make  status  not  converted in webpage. once the Cronjob  will run that time code will change PDF status COMPLETED. Cronjob will run every hours so site will update continues. so  the server will not have  much load

Comment: This seems like a good alternative if my idea doesn't work. I'll use this if I can't get it to work any other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the appropriate way to do this in PHP would be to execute a separate process using one of the functions `exec`, `system`, 'pcntl_exec`,`popen`, etc.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about PHP (I just started using it, so I know what I need to know and not much more), but would calling exec(parsePDFFile.php) work? Can I make a PHP file executable (Google says yes, but is is as simple as calling it?)? If it can be executed, does calling exec on a PHP file let the file execute fully or does it stop being executed when I leave the page? In other words, does calling exec on a PHP file make the PHP execute on its own without having any connection to the file that called it?

Answer (score 0):

you could set up a cronjob doing this like every minute, check if new pdfs are there and then run your script.

Comment: But using cronjob is also a problem. It will make too load on server.

Comment: I thought about this approach as well, but since I don't really know much about cron jobs I thought that checking every minute might put a load on the server? Would it even matter?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough access to the server to setup cron, I'll assume you have enough to install PHP extensions ...

If that is the case, then I think what you want here is multiple threads outside of the website/webserver process. One thread should probably run as a daemon ( doesn't literally need to be a thread, this can be the main process of PHP ) and scan for new pdf's periodically, or on demand if you know anything about conditions and mutex - you could send a signal to the master thread ( or process, they can use mutex/conditions too ) when a user uploads that way. This should then dispatch new threads to deal with each pdf and continue the job of scanning or waiting for notification ...

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Possible :)